# openapi-generator-maven-plugin not finding mustache template on Windows

Tags: java, windows, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` Version 6.6.0 on a Windows machine and want to generate server stubs with the `jaxrs-jersey` or `jaxrs-spec` generator from an openapi 3.0.3 yaml definiton. In my understanding I must modify some mustache templates to be able to inject some delegator classes with my business logic into the generated stubs. So I put the `api.mustache` file into `src/main/resources/templates/` but it is simply ignored by the generator. I suspect some issue with path resolving, debug output gets me:

```
"inputSpec" : "C:\\workspace\\path\\project\\submodule/src/main/resources/api.yaml",

"templateDir" : "C:\\workspace\\path\\project\\submodule\\src\\main\\resources\\templates",
```

For the path definitions in the `pom.xml` plugin config I have tried with the same result:

```
<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates</templateDirectory>
                                                                                              

<templateResourcePath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates</templateResourcePath>
```

Note that the `api.yaml` input spec is found by the generator and that the file separators differ. Any idea how I can get the generator to pick up the templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is kind of embarrassing, it was a typo. I somehow named the template file `api.moustache` instead of `api.mustache`. After correcting the typo the template is picked up.